# SQL table not able to join tables correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently working on 2 tables as shown in picture below. Trying to get the Output Where LotName = LotAA, Where LotName = LotDD. But I keep getting the wrong output as shown in the image 2.
[image]

[image]

```
select * from lot l
left join lotlots ll on l.LotID = ll.Lots
left join lot l2 on l2.LotID = ll.LotID
where l.LotName = 'LotAA'
```

I got so much confusion trying to join the tables to get the name because the Where condition need to be search by LotName. Which join should use in order to get the desired result? I've tried using inner join and left join, but still not able to get the desired output in image 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the join field order flipped:

Change

```
left join lotlots ll on l.LotID = ll.Lots
left join lot l2 on l2.LotID = ll.LotID
```

To

```
left join lotlots ll on l.LotID = ll.LotID
left join lot l2 on l2.LotID = ll.Lots
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your joint seems to be incorrect, Try the query below. Inner join is apt for the scenario.

```
select l.lotName,l2.LotName Lotlotsname from lot l
inner join lotlots ll on l.LotID = ll.LotId
inner join lot l2 on l2.LotID = ll.Lots
where l.LotName = 'LotAA'
```

Output will be ,

```
Lotname Lotlotsname
LotAA   LotCC
LotAA   LotDD
```

Refer dbfiddle for complete solution :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a6448a8d7c6963a31d92de5eac71ff8